# 変更により動作しなくなったJavaScriptのデバッグ・修正方法が知りたい

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、午前０時に日付が自動的に変わる"(カレンダー機能つき)デジタル時計"で、
その文字列がマウスポインターに付いて回ります。
ここで、問題があります。
それは、自動更新する箇所の"drag = function(){}"の中に表示文字を入れると
その和暦の文字列の移動速度が重くなるため、コードを工夫したつもりですが、
機能しなくなりました。問題箇所は"digi関数"内ですが、うまく組み立てられる形は、
教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>文字マウスストーカー</title>


<style type="text/css">

#myText {
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
color: gold;

position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;}
#myText div {position: relative;}
#myText div div {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;text-align: center;}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--


var msg =  "";


var size = 24;

var circleY = 0.75; var circleX = 2;

var letter_spacing = 5;

var diameter = 10;

var rotation = 0.4;
var speed = 0.3;

if (!window.addEventListener
    && !window.attachEvent
    || !document.createElement)
    throw 'error';

msg = msg.split('');
var n = msg.length - 1, a = Math.round(size * diameter * 0.208333), currStep = 20,
ymouse = a * circleY + 20, xmouse = a * circleX + 20, y = [], x = [], Y = [], X = [],
o = document.createElement('div'), oi = document.createElement('div'),
b = document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat"? document.documentElement : document.body,

mouse = function(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 ymouse = !isNaN(e.pageY)? e.pageY : e.clientY; // y-position
 xmouse = !isNaN(e.pageX)? e.pageX : e.clientX; // x-position
},

makecircle = function(){ // rotation/positioning

 if(init.nopy){
  o.style.top = (b || document.body).scrollTop + 'px';
  o.style.left = (b || document.body).scrollLeft + 'px';
 };
 currStep -= rotation;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){ // makes the circle
  d = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).style;
  d.top = Math.round(y[i] + a * Math.sin((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleY - 15) + 'px';
  d.left = Math.round(x[i] + a * Math.cos((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleX) + 'px';
 };
},

var tMsg = ' ';
var lastTLocale = '';

function digi(){

  var t = tMsg;

var time = new Date();
var Hour = time.getHours();

 if(Hour < 12){
      if(lastTLocale!= 'info1'){

          var date = new Date(),

              m = new Array("１月", "２月", "３月", "４月", "５月", "６月", "７月", "８月", "９月", "10月", "11月", "12月"),
              w = new Array("㊐", "㊊", "㊋", "㊌", "㊍", "㊎", "㊏"),
             Wareki = date.getFullYear(),
             month = m[date.getMonth()],
             day = date.getDate(),
             week = w[date.getDay()],
     Hour = date.getHours(),
     Min = date.getMinutes(),
     Sec = date.getSeconds();

        if(Hour <= 9) { 
                       Hour = "0" + Hour; 
}        
　　　　if(Min <= 9) { 
                       Min = "0" + Min; 
}
        if(Sec <= 9) { 
                       Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
}

         var Eto = new Array("子", "丑", "寅", "卯", "辰", "巳", "午", "未", "申", "酉", "戌", "亥"),
             EtoNum = (Wareki + 8) % 12;

           t =  Eto[EtoNum] + "◆" + " " + month + day + "日" + " " + week + " " + "★" + "★" + " " + date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "").replace(/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1元') + " " +  "◆" +  Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;
          lastTLocale = 'info1';

}

else{

      if(lastTLocale != 'info2'){

          var date = new Date(),
              m = new Array("１月", "２月", "３月", "４月", "５月", "６月", "７月", "８月", "９月", "10月", "11月", "12月"),
              w = new Array("㊐", "㊊", "㊋", "㊌", "㊍", "㊎", "㊏"),
             Wareki = date.getFullYear(),
             month = m[date.getMonth()],
             day = date.getDate(),
             week = w[date.getDay()],
     Hour = date.getHours(),
     Min = date.getMinutes(),
     Sec = date.getSeconds();

         var Eto = new Array("子", "丑", "寅", "卯", "辰", "巳", "午", "未", "申", "酉", "戌", "亥"),
             EtoNum = (Wareki + 8) % 12;

           t =  Eto[EtoNum] + "◆" + " " + month + day + "日" + " " + week + " " + "★" + "★" + " " + date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "").replace(/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1元') + " " +  "◆" +  Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;
          lastTLocale = 'info2';
}

    var currentLength = msg.length;

  if (t != tMsg) {
    tMsg=t;

    // 状態の変更
    msg = t.split('');
    n = msg.length - 1;

    // 文字要素の変更
    for (var i = Math.max(currentLength, msg.length) - 1; i > -1; --i)
    {
        var d = i < currentLength ? document.getElementById('iemsg' + i) : null;
        if (d)
        {
            if (i < t.length)
            {
                // 既存要素の内容変更
                d.innerHTML = msg[i];
            }
            else
            {
                // 不要になった要素の削除
                d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // 不足要素の追加
            d = document.createElement('div');
            d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
            d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
            d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
            oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
        }
    }
};

drag = function(){
 y[0] = Y[0] += (ymouse - Y[0]) * speed;
 x[0] = X[0] += (xmouse - 20 - X[0]) * speed;
 for (var i = n; i > 0; --i){
  y[i] = Y[i] += (y[i-1] - Y[i]) * speed;
  x[i] = X[i] += (x[i-1] - X[i]) * speed;
 };
 makecircle();digi();
},

init = function(){
 if(!isNaN(window.pageYOffset)){
  ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
  xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 } else init.nopy = true;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
  d = document.createElement('div'); d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
  d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
  oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
 };
 o.appendChild(oi); document.body.appendChild(o);
 setInterval(drag, 25);
},

ascroll = function(){

 ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
 xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 window.removeEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
};

o.id = 'myText'; o.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

if (window.addEventListener){

 window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
 document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouse, false);
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse, false);
  if (/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor))
   window.addEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent){
 window.attachEvent('onload', init);
 document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouse);
}

// -->
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="black">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 102行目に全角スペースが含まれていたり、いくつかの構文エラーがあります。
- イベントリスナ登録処理が呼び出さされるように、グローバルスコープに切り出す必要があります
- `setInterval()` やイベントリスナから呼びだされる `init()`, `drag()` を適切なスコープに含める必要があります

ひとまず、最低限動作するように修正してみたものが下記です。
https://gist.github.com/temmings/0f1a6a9eed6e60921f74b115f3c41563/8421e68fede9b09d5a59268ac770a665768521f2

どのような修正を加えたかは下記URLを参照ください。
https://gist.github.com/temmings/0f1a6a9eed6e60921f74b115f3c41563/revisions?diff=split

構文エラーが多いため、ブラウザのコンソールのメッセージを確認されることをお勧めします。
例えば Google Chrome であれば、`F12` or `Ctrl + Shift + I` でデバッグコンソールを起動でき、下記のようなエラーメッセージが確認できます。

> a.html:74 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

JavaScript を JSLint などの Lint ツールでチェックするのもいいと思います。
- https://www.jslint.com/

Comment: 回答をありがとうございました。修正コードはエラーは出ませんが、動作しません。

Comment: `if(Hour < 12)` とあるので、午前中しか動作しないですね。

Comment: 自動更新させたいので、午前(ifHour < 12))と午後(else)に分けています。動かないということは、どこか論理が合っていないのでしょう。

Comment: ちょっとおっしゃっている意味が分かりかねますが、インデント・書式の修正や、冗長性を排除してみました。おそらくこういう動作を想定されているのではないでしょうか。(デバッグのために12月31日23時59分50秒から始まるようにしています) https://gist.github.com/temmings/0f1a6a9eed6e60921f74b115f3c41563/1683a0bd5a288fa9af74ef7b0a53b4a9d015bdbf

Comment: 勘違いしていました。動いています。すみませんでした。しかし、toLocaleDateStringの"西暦"に比べると"和暦"は、IEでは異常に重い(遅い)のです。そこを何とかならないものかと考えているのです。

Comment: IEの話は初出ですね。例えば "IE(動作確認したバージョン)上で`Date#toLocaleDateString`で和暦を扱う場合、西暦を扱う場合と比較してパフォーマンスが落ちてしまう問題を解決したい" のようなトピックで質問されてみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: @user28531 追加情報をコメントに記載しないでください。質問文を`編集`を選択して修正して追記してください。また、質問する際は環境を事前に記載すると二度手間になりません。